# Induction well ordering principle

Tags: induction

Can someone help me with the following question. I have mangaged to solve this question using well ordering prinicple but cant proof it by the induction method. I cant proof that n+1 holds in the equation. Please be as detailed as possible. The question could be found in link below, it is listed as question number 2.

> Prove by either the Well Ordering Principle or induction that for all nonnegative integers $n$:
>   $$\sum_{i=0}^n i^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2.\tag1$$

.[MIT Assignment question2](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_042JF10_assn02.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

See, for $n=0,1$, statement is true.Now assume that statement is true for $n=k$ i.e. $\sum_{i=0}^k i^3 = \left(\frac{k(k+1)}2\right)^2.\tag1$, then you have to show for $n=k+1$ statement also holds.
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} i^3 = \sum_{i=0}^k i^3+(k+1)^3$$. Now using equation (1) we have, $$\begin{align*}\left(\frac{k(k+1)}2\right)^2+(k+1)^3
&= \frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4} + (k+1)^3\\
&= \frac{k^2(k+1)^2 + 4(k+1)^3}{4}\\
&= \frac{(k+1)^2(k^2 + 4k + 4)}{4}\\
&= \frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}.\\
&= \frac{(k+1)^2((k+1)+1)^2}{4}
&=\left(\frac{(k+1)((k+1)+1)}2\right)^2
\end{align*}$$

Hence, statement holds for $n=k+1$. Then by Principle of induction statement is true for all $n$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $F(n)= \sum_{i=0}^n i^3$ and use : $F(n)-F(n-1)=n^3$ (here is used induction).

This gives:
$$
\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{(n-1)n}{2}\right)^2=n^3
$$
That you can easely verify.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by Induction:

Base Case:
For n = 1, LHS = 1, RHS = $(\frac{1*2}{2})^2$ = 1

Induction Hypothesis:
For some n, assume $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3 = (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2$

For n+1, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} i^3 = (\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2 + (n+1)^3$

$= (n+1)^2 (\frac{n^2 + 4n + 4}{4})$
   $= (\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2})^2$